# Printing text from BeautifulSoup object, excluding certain tags? [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

If you have a BS object, for example:

```
>>> print soup
<div>
   Peter Griffin
   <br>
   Lois Griffin
   <br>
   Chris Griffin
   <br>
   <div> Meg Griffin </div>
   <br>
   Stewie Griffin
   <br>
<div>
```

How could you print `soup.text` excluding everything inside the inner `<div>`?

The output I want is:

```
>>> print <clever_code>
Peter Griffin
Lois Griffin
Chris Griffin
Stewie Griffin
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to remove inner `<div>` tags and print the text of the `soup` after removing extra spaces:

```
for tag in soup.select('div div'):
    tag.clear()
print('\n'.join(re.split(r'\s*\n+\s*', soup.text.strip())))
```

It yields:

```
Peter Griffin
Lois Griffin
Chris Griffin
Stewie Griffin
```

Comment: +1 For answering my question within the BeautifulSoup parameters, although I really don't see the need for `Regex` here. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob-IT: The `regex` it's to collapse spaces between strings

Answer (score 1):

Use a class that builds on a module from Python's stdlib...

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class HTML_tag_stripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = HTML_tag_stripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()

>>> print strip_tags( str(soup) )
```

Comment: Ah..this makes sense now that I look at it. Thanks, and just out of curiosity, is there a way native to BS to perform this task?

Comment: Not that I know of. Besides, native is better. :)

Comment: Hmmm...when I run this code I get an error:

`s.feed(html)`

`File "C:\Python27\lib\HTMLParser.py", line 113, in feed`

`self.rawdata = self.rawdata + data`

`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Tag' objects`

Comment: I just tested without error, but you have a real world situation. You probably need to cast something to str.